# Increase of Googlebot response time after CDN implementation

Tags: seo, cdn, cloudflare

**Problem**: We have a site hosted in Germany that is suffixed with ".de". Recently, we implemented a CDN with Cloudflare. Shortly after our Googlebot response times increased from 60-100ms to 400-500ms. We noticed that the origin from Googlebot requests come from the US. However, this is the usual case as we learned.

There are solution to overcome this, e.g. Caching. However, our goal is to understand the underlying change that led to the increase. We have reviewed a lot of our config in the last days and haven't yet understood the problem. Cloudflare uses anycast ips, thus a website can not necessarily be geolocated.

**Our current hypothesis**: The Googlebot takes into account that a site is hosted on a different continent and subtracts a certain amount of response time.

**Question aim**: Receive hints what to look for to understand the underlying cause.

Comment: Are you saying that you are currently using Cloudflare without any caching?   I didn't even know that was possible.  The point of a CDN is to serve up a cached version from the edge nodes when possible.